# multiple insertion in cakephp 3.8

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.8

I should make a multiple listing. where two fields have the same values in common. For example, if I enter Inter, Milan, Juve they will have nationality_season and series_season as common fields. Furthermore, the user should decide on the number of advertisements to be made.

only that when I go to insert everything: Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'club_id' doesn't have a default value

[image]

i have this database

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `championships`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `championships` (
  `id` int(11),
  `club_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `season` varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
  `nationality_championship` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `championship_series` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `penal` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `clubs`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clubs` (
  `id` int(11),
  `name` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' '
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE clubs
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE championships
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD FOREIGN KEY(club_id) REFERENCES clubs(id);
```

[image]

the function that manages the insertion is the add function in the championships controller:

```
 public function add()
    {

        $championship = $this->Championships->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $championship = $this->Championships->patchEntity($championship, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Championships->save($championship)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The championship has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The championship could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }

        $clubsUnmated=$this->Championships->Clubs->find('list',['keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' =>['nome_societa']])->notMatching('Championships');

        $this->set(compact('championship', 'clubsUnmated'));
    }
```

extract code add.ctp:

```
<div class="championships form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($championship) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Championship') ?></legend>
        <?php

            echo $this->Form->control('season',['class'=>'form-control']);
            echo $this->Form->control('nazionalità_campionato',['class'=>'form-control']);
            echo $this->Form->control('serie_campionato',['class'=>'form-control']);
            echo $this->Form->control('club_id', ['options' => $clubsUnmated,'data-role'=>'tagsinput','type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'aggiungi squadre','class'=>'form-control']);

        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your form controls have different field names than your database schema is showing for `nationality_championship` and `championship_series`. That's not causing this problem, but it'll be a problem soon.

The main thing here is that it looks like you're going to be getting an array of values from your `club_id`, but the field in the database is a single value. If you want to stick with this database schema, you're going to have to loop over that array (which should probably be called something else in your form, to avoid issues when creating your entities to save). For example, if you rename that control to `clubs`, then it might look something like this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $championships = [];
    $data = $this->request->getData();
    foreach ($data['clubs'] as $club_id) {
        $championships[] = $this->Championships->newEntity(array_merge($data, compact('club_id')));
    }
    if ($this->Championships->saveMany($championships)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The championship has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The championship could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
```

But even that probably isn't what you really want, as it's repeating the championship data many times in your database. I think what you really want is not to have `club_id` in that table at all, but rather have a `championships_clubs` join table, and then you can probably just name your `club_id` control as `clubs._ids` and your original patch and save code will work fine to create the whole record structure.

Comment: yes the fields were in Italian and I translated them to make them more understandable for comunity. So the names are correct it is just a typo. Sorry

Comment: what i would like to do is a multiple addition in the championships table. Basically I would like to add N ennuple in the table where for each team I repeat some fields every time.   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvPPp.png it serves to give an example of what I would like to do

Comment: That should be accomplished by the code I provided. But it's bad database design to have the championship data repeated so many times. What happens when you realize that you made an error and need to update 10 rows?

Comment: what would be a correct design of the DB?thanks again for the support. the problem is of the type: each club can only enroll in one league each year. We need to keep track of the various leagues over the years. So every club makes a new league every year

Comment: As I said, what you really want is not to have `club_id` in that table at all, but rather have a `championships_clubs` join table.